# jquery.mmenu not working with exact same demo code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mmenu, typeerror

http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

1. Local version of the menu works
2. Doesn't work when uploaded onto my server. However, the demo version it comes with still works...

Error it gives is Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for the .mmenu() function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('nav#menu').mmenu();
            });
</script>
```

The function is defined, however, in

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery.mmenu-master/src/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />
```

AND jquery is also attached

any thoughts?

Edit: The following is my header info (in case it might help)

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=yes" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery.mmenu-master/src/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.mmenu-master/src/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('nav#menu').mmenu();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi Cerlin, thanks for the your quick respsonse. Yes, jquery is attached. It works fine locally too

Comment: you have included two jquery. remove the first one

Comment: Just removed and uploaded, but still doesn't work :/

Comment: check if mmenu js file is a 404.

Comment: if possible then make a fiddle..

Comment: It's linked correctly - checked, and the menu actually works locally. Just stops working once uploaded

Comment: things you have to check is; if jquery is properly initialized (use `console.log($)` to log and check. you can also use `jQuery` instead of `$`) , the plugin is properly initialized and `'nav#menu'` element is actually present

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just check console.log(2) and generated an output of function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}
undefined

Comment: console.log($)*, and replaced $ with jquery and doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

use the java-scripts and css hosted on their website rather than one in the example also it seems you need to decorate the  element with the following class mm-current